# Adaptive 2-column layout

Tags: html, css

I'm working on site with adaptive layout, this means site adapts to user screen width.
There are three images illustrating my idea, images are showing three steps of brower window resize from wide to narrow.

**Wide screen**
the purple area sticks to left side of the page and green area fits the rest of the screen.

[image: wide screen]

**Medium screen**
the green area reached its minimum width
[image: medium screen]

**Narrow screen**
green area jump under the purple area

[image: narrow screen]

I use the following styles

```
.purple_block {
    float: left;
    width: 751px;
    height: 504px;
    margin: 0 35px 100px 0;
}

.green_block{
    min-width: 400px;
}
```

But this 'min-width' doesn't work, as the green block width is calculated from the left edge of the purple area till the right edge of the green area.

How to achive the desired behaviour?

**UPDATE**
the purple block should be fixed always (it is a project gallery actually).
the green block should have margin from purple block and look like a column that fits all the space left (it is a project description: several paragraphs of text + links).
When user narrowing its browser green block get narrower too. When green block reaches its min-width it jumps under the purple block.

Comment: are you using media queries to change styles for different viewport widths?

Comment: If I get you right, site is JavaScript enabled and there are heavy code to do different things, but I want this layout to work without any javascript.

Comment: media queries are a feature of CSS: http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Comment: OK I got it.  But I hope this behaviour can be reached without media queries. Am I wrong?

Comment: if you can provide more specific requirements for the desired behavior, we may be able to help more. For wide screens, should there be a margin between the two elements? For narrow screens, should both elements fill 100% of the viewport width? When exactly does the green element jump from the side of the purple element to below it. At the moment, it looks like you'll need some logic dictating when the styles on your elements change.

Comment: yes, I can provide more specific requirements, see update in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need screen-size specific CSS. You can define that by using

```
@media only screen and (max-width: ...px) { ... }
```

So for every state (your individual images show them) you define the CSS that should change at that browser window width.

E.g.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    .purple_block {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
        height: 504px;
        margin: 0 35px 100px 0;
    }

    .green_block{
        width: 100%;
        height: 300px;
    }
}
```

And so on.

Comment: Thank You for advice, I will use it also. But I hope this behaviour can be reached without media queries.

Comment: seems to me that it is the only one solution.